# How to disable button if no text in textfield?

Tags: ios, uibutton, uitextfield, uitextview

I need help with an app I'm making in Xcode. I have a note submission part of my app. What code should I implement to disable the "save" button until text has been entered into the textfield? Thanks in advance:3

Comment: Have you tried anything? What research have you made?

Comment: actually the solution is simple -> check if there is text in `textField` if so -> enable button else disable.

Comment: @Roma-MT what code would be required for that? I am somewhat new to Objective-C so it would be appreciated!! & Leo Natan I have researched other answers on here but none of them seem to be working. Thanks guys

Comment: show us ur code than I can make an answer codewise as u wish.
also JMarsh answer is ur answer .

Comment: I have no code regarding this task yet haha. Since I am new, I don't know how to apply what he is asking to my app. I will be submitting my app this week so I actually need a partner to collaborate with. You'd get partial credit in making the app too!!

Comment: So you don't have save button and not even the text field ?

Comment: I have both. It's a notes app & everything thing else is functioning correctly.

Comment: So put it, also put your .h file , then I can point you appropriately
otherwise I can only provide theoretical answer and not coding1 

put your .h and the code connecting to it e.g. init of the text field and the button (P.S. I am not interested in taking partial credit).

Comment: I see it is going nowhere...
make textfield delegate , then use 2 answers from below  and it will do the magic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement UITextViewDelegate and use `textViewDidChange` to track all changes made in your `UITextView`. In there you can simply check if the textView's text length is greater than 0, if it is then enable the "Save" button, otherwise disable it.

Answer (score 1):

What have you tried? There is a simple solution for this :

```
mybutton.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

That is the code for setting interaction off, and what you will need to do is wait for the first responder to be active

When a user clicks on the area to type you grab the keyboard I assume by setting the first responder - well when you do this just set the userinteraction = YES, and at any time that the textfield is non active use the line above.

A

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What specific code would I need to enter?

Comment: How do you currently have the keyboard popping up? Lets see some of the code you have